# Increment number in JSON file with python

Tags: python, json

I'm learing on how json files work, and I was tryng to make something that I thought it was simple, but I've been having problems, I have this code:

```
import json

id = 696969969696
warns = 10

with open('warn.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    guilds_dict = json.load(f)
    guilds_dict[str(id)] = warns

with open('warn.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(guilds_dict, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

That when is executed adds `id` and `warns` to the JSON file looking like this:

```
{
    "696969969696": "10"
}
```

So, I wanted to do that in case that `id` already exists adds the numbers that `warn` has, here is an example:

```
id = 696969969696
warns = 2
{
    "696969969696": "10"
}
```

> after executed:

```
{
    "696969969696": "12"
}
```

How can I do this, and if it's possible i would like to understand it not only copy paste.
Thanks!

Comment: Probably several ways, easiest is to use `if` to see if the key already exists. There are also improved dictionary structures where values default to whatever you want, so you can just use + blindly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, two notes:

- Once the json is loaded, it is a regular python dictionary. This operation is essentially unrelated to json.
- `id` is already a function in python, used to get the memory address of an object. It's generally recommended to avoid overriding builtins; consider using `id_` instead.

---

That said, there are at least three ways to do this:

```python3
guilds_dict[str(id)] = guilds_dict.get(str(id), 0) + warns
```

where `guilds_dict.get(str(id), 0)` gets the value if it already exists, or `0` otherwise, then adds the new value.

```python3
from collections import defaultdict
guilds_dict = defaultdict(int, gilds_dict)
guilds_dict[str(id)] += warns
```

where a `defaultdict` is a dictionary that automatically fills with `0` if the key is gotten before it is set.

```python3
if str(id) in guilds_dict:
    guilds_dict[str(id)] += warns
else:
    guilds_dict[str(id)] = warns
```

where `str(id) in guilds_dict` checks if the key exists.

Answer (score 0):

first off you should check out the [documentation on dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

From the documentation:

> To check whether a single key is in the dictionary, use the in keyword.

So you can do `if str(id) in guilds_dict`. Then you will need to handle the addition of the two values (which I notice are strings so be careful there).